# Sending sms through smsManager stoppeed working

Tags: java, android

I made an app to read values from the database and send messages through the smsManager and it was perfectly fine but all of a sudden it stopped working, Anybody have any idea what could be the cause? It returns sent status but the messages are not being sent in reality.  Here is the code:

```
     package com.brs;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Sahil on 17-06-2015.
 */
public class Sending extends IntentService {

    public static int cursor_count=0;

   public Sending()
   {
       super("Sending");
   }

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase;
    DatabaseHandler databasehandler;
    Cursor cursor, cursor2;
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

        databasehandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        sqliteDatabase = databasehandler.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = databasehandler.read_queue(sqliteDatabase);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        System.out.println("The Vlaues for cursor : " + cursor.getCount());
        //cursor_count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor2 = databasehandler.read_polls(sqliteDatabase);
        System.out.println("The Vlaues for cursor2 : " + cursor2.getCount());
        int t = 0;

        //To reach the first pending statement.
        do {
            String stats;
            stats = cursor.getString(2);
            System.out.println("The status is " + stats);
            if (stats.matches("PENDING")) {
                System.out.println("THE DEBUG CHECKER");
                t = 1;
                break;
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        if (t == 1)
        {
                do
                {
                    String ques = "", opt1 = "", opt2 = "", opt3 = "", opt4 = "", opt5 = "", keyword = "", start_date = "", end_date = "", message = "";
                    int k = cursor.getInt(0);
                    System.out.println("The cursor index:" + k);
                    if (cursor2.moveToFirst())
                    {
                    do
                    {
                            int pol_id;
                            pol_id = cursor2.getInt(0);
                            if (pol_id == k)
                            {
                            ques = cursor2.getString(1);
                            opt1 = cursor2.getString(2);
                            opt2 = cursor2.getString(3);
                            opt3 = cursor2.getString(4);
                            opt4 = cursor2.getString(5);
                            opt5 = cursor2.getString(6);
                            keyword = cursor2.getString(7);
                            start_date = cursor2.getString(8);
                            end_date = cursor2.getString(9);
                            message = cursor2.getString(10);
                            break;
                            }
                    } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        int id;
                        String number;
                        String status;
                        id = cursor.getInt(0);
                        number = cursor.getString(1);
                        status = cursor.getString(2);
                        System.out.println("The id :" + id);
                        System.out.println("The number:" + number);
                        System.out.println("The status :" + status);
                        if (id == k) {
                            String sms;
                            if (message.matches("")) {
                                sms = ques + "\nA." + opt1 + "\nB." + opt2 + "\nC." + opt3 + "\nD." + opt4 + "\nE." + opt5 + "\nSTART DATE:" + start_date + "\nEND DATE:" + end_date + "\nReply in the below given format:\n" + id + " " + keyword + " (A|B|C|D|E)";
                            } else {
                                sms = message + "\nSTART DATE:" + start_date + "\nEND DATE:" + end_date + "\nReply in the below given format:\n" + id + " " + keyword + " (A|B|C|D|E)\nResponses in Invalid format would not be processed.\nSent from GOLL_POLL";
                            }

                            try {
                                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                PendingIntent sentPI;
                                String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
                                sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, sms, sentPI, null);
                                databasehandler.update_queue(id, number, "SENT");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                databasehandler.update_queue(id, number, "FAIL");
                                System.out.println("Message sending failed");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("The status:" + cursor.getString(2));

                            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                        }
                    }, 40000);
                cursor.moveToPrevious();
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            System.out.println("The end has been reached:");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If your message has become longer than the character limit for a simple SMS, you'll have to use the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method instead.